# prn parameter in Scapy

Tags: python, callback, scapy, abbreviation

Is the parameter `prn` in the `sniff-function` of`Scapy` an abbreviation for anything?

I know it is used to define a `callback-function` for the sniffed packet, I just can't find the meaning of `prn`.

I couldn't find an explanation for the abbreviation in the [documentation](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably for "print", since the result of the callback (if it is not `None`) is printed.

The first (historical) use of this callback was to print, for example, a `.summary()` or a `.display()` of each sniffed packet (see the `tshark()` function).

Comment: That makes sense. Also found in the description of prn in [this documentation on Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf) that `If something is returned, it is displayed.`

Answer (score 3):

I found something interesting but I'm not sure if it's relevant or not.

> `PRN` is an abbreviation for the Latin term, "pro re nata" which loosely translates to "as needed." PRN is a term commonly used by healthcare employers and professionals to describe short-term, contract, part-time, or fill-in work by a nurse or allied health professional.

As `prn` takes the call-back function name, it sounds logical to me but I don't believe they would go this far to name a parameter.

Comment: I didn't know that. :p Now I feel ashamed. I just found it on the internet. That's all. :p